# How to search on Instagram posts (texts, not hashtags)?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

For example, I want to find all posts of containing word "book" in D. Trump's instagram.

If I go to google - it shows the results, but opens just main page of person's instagram, not the exact photo

https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA+%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB&oq=%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA+%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5528j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=book+site:instagram.com%2Frealdonaldtrump